# Excel VBA - Using the range function within a range function

Tags: vba, excel

There are 2 things to note here. The first: I am using a `For` loop to step through each row. The second: I don't know which is the last column with data in each row and hence I am trying to use the `Range.End` function to find it. To Select the last column with data in row x, the code that works is:

```
Cells(x, Range("C" & x).End(xlToRight).Column).Select
```

As you can see from the above, I am starting from column C, row X and looking for the last cell with data in that row. I don't think it matters which column I start from as Column A, B, C, D and E will definitely have data.

Now I try to select a range from Cells(x, 3) (or column C row X) to the above last cell with data in row x. The following code doesn't work:

```
Range("Cells(x,3):Cells(x, Range("C" & x).End(xlToRight).Column)").Select
```

I don't know if I am allowed to use the range function like that. The error is a compile error stating "expected: List separator or )" and it highlights the `C` in `Range("C" & x)` I looked carefully but don't see anything missing.

I highly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
Range(Cells(x,3), Cells(x, Range("C" & x).End(xlToRight).Column)).Select
```

Comment: Oh my hat. Let me just walk out and go kill myself! Dude, half an hour and I am like why oh why! Embarrassed is not the word! Anyway, I appreciate your help. I will accept answer in 10 minutes! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your method using `End(xlToRight)` will work only if your range is continous.

If you have blank cells in the middle of the range (let's say columns M and N are empty) you will not get the cells with data in Columns "O:X".

To `Select` the last column with data in row x, use:

```
Cells(x, Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Select
```

To `Select` the entire `Range` use:

```
Range(Cells(x, 3), Cells(x, Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Select
```

However, there is seldom a need to `Select`, if you "must" then it's better to first define a `Range`, like this:

```
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range(Cells(x, 3), Cells(x, Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
```

And later on, if you need to `Select` it use:

```
Rng.Select
```

Comment: Hi, it is continuous as data is pasting column by column until the last. I am then trying to select it to copy and move to word. All is working well now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KoderM16 ok, still, you should know the dangers in using `End(xlToRight)` and `End(xlDown)`